# Is it possible to exclude lombok features

Tags: lombok

Is it possible to use the configuration system to disallow certain features?

For example, if I use kotlin data classes or immutables for value/data objects, can I enforce this by telling lombok to ignore `Data/Value/Builder` annotation but still allow me to use other features like `Sneakythrows` or `RequiredArgsConstructor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by means of [Lombok configuration system](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration) and its `flagUsage` option.

You need a `lombok.config` file with the following content:

```
lombok.data.flagUsage = ERROR
lombok.value.flagUsage = ERROR
lombok.builder.flagUsage = ERROR
```

You put this file in a directory whose contents (including subdirectories) are to be affected by this configuration (typically, the root directory of the project).

Comment: Thanks, it works. But: Only when I run gradle build, not when I rebuild the project in IDEA. Any hint on that as well?

Comment: Hm, it works for me (I'm using IntelliJ too). Sorry if it sounds like a lame question but: have you got [IntelliJ Lombok plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok-plugin) installed and active?

Comment: Yes, that's active. I was refacturing my gradle build while checking the lombok usage, so it might just work alltogether when I am done setting up.